# Firebase: Add microsoft.com provider programatically

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

using Firebase's Admin SDK, it is possible to add a new Provider Config, either for SAML or OIDC. I'm creating new tenants for every account, to give our users the ability to create their own sign in methods.

Using the cloud console, it's possible to add Microsoft as an IdP for each tenant. Is there also a way to add this provider programmatically?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but recently looked into this myself.

The identity platform apis have endpoints for managing provider config.

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest#service:-identitytoolkit.googleapis.com

You should be able to manage tenant and project idp configs for various providers (including OID and SAML too)